# How to make sure I always have an API token?

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net, authorization

I am writing an API, in that API I sometimes need to make a call to another, remote API. This remote API needs an authorization token, which it gives if you call an appropriate method (for example, `/api/GetAuthToken?user=user&pass=pass`, where `user` and `pass` are hardcoded or passed to my API via settings file). Then you can use this token to call other methods, which I actually need. This token is valid for some time. If it expires, API calls return 401 - not authorized. My question is - what is the best way to make sure that I always have a "fresh", working token and always replace it when it expires? An API object is singleton, it may receive concurrent requests.

Comment: Can you state specifically what you mean by "best," without resorting to tautologies like "best practice" or "most popular?"  On the face of it, it would seem that a "good" way would be to simply request a new token when you get the 401.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most straightforward solution (therefore best in my opinion) would be to have a helper method that gets the api parameters as its parameters and simply calls the api with these. Then it checks the return code, with the condition that if 401 is recieved, it calls `GetAuthToken` then calls the api again.